# Exception creating bean of class weblogic 12c config

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, weblogic, struts

I have a structured project for jboss with strut jdk 1.6 and the idea is to migrate it to weblogic 12c, apart from this I already migrated another project with the same structure only that based on jdk 1.7 and everything worked fine, but for this one with the same changes, at the time of deployment, everything is fine, but when you enter the web route the following error message appears:

```
Remote Host: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
URL: http://localhost:7001/oficinavirtual/pages/ingreso.jsp
URI: /oficinavirtual/pages/ingreso.jsp
Server Name: localhost
<15/05/2018 17h'33 ART> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@239123345[app:OficinaVirtualProj module:/oficinavirtual path:null spec-version:3.1], request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@2ae9b08b[
GET /oficinavirtual/pages/ingreso.jsp HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9

]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class ar.com.gnb.oficinavirtual.struts.forms.LoginForm: {1}
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.initFormBean(FormTag.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:520)
    at jsp_servlet._pages.__ingreso._jspService(__ingreso.java:215)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I would appreciate very much illuminating me a little.

Comment: Perhaps the rest of the stacktrace would be important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The error was that weblogic needs the struts library internally in its classpath, it is not enough for the web application to have it internally as was the case with jboss, apart I added the libraries of javax.servlet and javax.servlet.jsp and it worked